# Looking for Oracle Database and management tool for developing

Tags: web-development, database

I'm looking for Oracle Database and management tool for developing. Something like mysql and phpmyadmin. I'm using GlassFish as a Server. Platform Windows 64-bit and free (but no code licensing requirements).

Comment: What pricing? Do you need open-source (and if so any licensing requirements)?

Comment: It's just for developing and testing. Free and no licensing requirements.

Comment: What comes to my mind is Martijn Tonies' Database Workbench (www.upscene.com), but at this moment his free lite version is unavailable (he is at 4.4.5, 4.4.3 still had the lite version available). Very versatile tool (so much so that I actually bough the Pro version for an earlier release). See http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.index.php, http://www.upscene.com/downloads.php#dbw and http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.featurematrix.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) (free, Windows/Max/Linux, widely used):

> Oracle SQL Developer is a free integrated development environment that
>   simplifies the development and management of Oracle Database. SQL
>   Developer offers complete end-to-end development of your PL/SQL
>   applications, a worksheet for running queries and scripts, a DBA
>   console for managing the database, a reports interface, a complete
>   data modeling solution, and a migration platform for moving your 3rd
>   party databases to Oracle.

[image]

[image]